# Transaction relay behaviour with anonymity networks

Tags: daemon, network, i2p, tor

The [anonymity network doc](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/docs/ANONYMITY_NETWORKS.md) says:

> If any anonymity network is enabled, transactions being broadcast that lack a valid "context" (i.e. the transaction did not come from a p2p connection), will only be sent to peers on anonymity networks.

Why this behavior was chosen? Does this mean that a transaction will never make it to a block if no miner is connected to an anonymity network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that a transaction will never make it to a block if no miner is connected to an anonymity network?

No. Let me highlight something:

```
(i.e. the transaction did not come from a p2p connection)
```

What that means is that a node on an anonymity network will not broadcast a tx it receives directly from, for example, a wallet (which uses RPC), to *clearnet* peers. If a tx is received via p2p (i.e. another node), it will be broadcast as usual.

> Why this behavior was chosen?

I suppose as the intent of a wallet using an anonymity node is to have it's tx first broadcast over the anonymity network, not immediately broadcast to clearnet peers.